# Mostrar una imagen guardada de manera local en C# MVC

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Necesito poder cargar la imagen almacenada de manera local, para visualizarlo en en la vista, pero en la vista no se como puedo visualizarlo. En la base datos solo me almacena la ruta del archivo

Controlador

```
public string SaveFileToLocalFolder(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            string LocalPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalFileFolder"].ToString();
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Convert.ToString(guid));
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            string fileLocation = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(LocalPath), fileName+fileExtension);
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(LocalPath)))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(LocalPath));
            file.SaveAs(fileLocation);
            return fileLocation;
        }
```

Vista:

```
<img src="@Url.Content" width="250" height="200" />
```

Comment: Me parece que tu problema radica en que estás guardando la ruta absoluta en tu base de datos, y al momento de ponerla en el img src por eso no sale. Tendrías que convertir la ruta absoluta a ruta relativa. Checate este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164/absolute-path-back-to-web-relative-path

Comment: en la db guardas una ruta absoluta o relativa al archivo ? lo pregunto para saber si el archivo esta dentro de la estructura del sitio o en una carpeta diferente

Comment: bueno me guarda la ruta absoluta, y el archivo se guarda dentro del proyecto que en este caso se llama la carpeta ~/Content/LocalFiles.

Comment: @AlfredoManuelCanReséndiz y en donde va este codiigo: String RelativePath = AbsolutePath.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], String.Empty); en el proyecto soy nuevo en c#

Comment: Mira encontré un mejor ejemplo 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042861/how-to-make-an-absolute-path-relative-to-a-particular-folder